# Reproduce a simple Foreach-loop in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a simple foreach-sortof loop . It doesnt seem that foreach exists in Android, however i am clueless on how to fix this...

I am trying to print out a block of info, and on every block theres new info.. A simple loop...

This is what i've came up with so far :

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    String[] separated_nodes = node.split(":");


if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
    if(tag.equals("ChannelPackage")) {

                         // ArtNr:Name:Price:Period:InitDisPeriod:DisPeriod

                         // text.setText("Network "+xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "Name"));

                             packagename += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[1].trim());   
                             artnr += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[0].trim());                         
                             price += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[2].trim());                         
                             period += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[3].trim());                        
                             initdisperiod += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[4].trim());                        
                             disperiod += xpp.getAttributeValue(null, separated_nodes[5].trim());


                             text.setText("Channel Packages: \n" + artnr +"\n" +
                                        "Package Name: "+ packagename + "\n" +
                                        "Price : "+ price +"\n" +
                                        "Period: "+ period +"\n" +
                                        "InitDisPeriod: "+ initdisperiod +"\n" +
                                        "DisPeriod: "+ disperiod +"\n"
                                        );


                         text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

                     }

                 } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
                         System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());


                 } 
                 eventType = xpp.next();
                }

               // text.setText(nodes.toString());
            }catch(Exception ex){
                text.setText("Failed!");
                Log.i("HTTPResponse", ex.toString());
            }
```

But the result is like this:

- Artnr
- Artnr
- Artnr
- Packagename
- Packagename
- Packagename

But i want :

- Artnr
- Packagename
- Artnr
- Packagename

How can i format my code to get that result ? i am completely clueless :/

Comment: "packagename =" instead of "packagename +="

Comment: That gives me 1 result (the last result in the xml-string), i want it to loop.

Answer (score 2):

If the object you're iterating over extends Collection of type T you can do a foreach loop like this

```
for(T obj : someCollection) {
    // do something
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, it seems to me that the question isn't really about the foreach loop (I don't think you can use int whith this parser) but that you're getting the elements from your xml in the wrong order. Maybe you should consider using `nextTag()` instead of `next()`?

Comment: And for this, do i have to do a for() for all of my string-variables here, or just one ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, and after carefully reading your code I can't tell what you want to iterate over (is it 'separated_nodes'?). Could you clear up the question?

Comment: I've added more code to this, i thought i only needed that if-block :). I want to make 1 block of text with .setText. Loop through each tag.equals("ChannelPackage"), and print it out.

Comment: You iterate over the collection that contains your `xpp` objects. If I understood it right what you are trying to do, the code you provided belongs in the block of the foreach loop.

Comment: If i changed next() to nextTag(), it printed "Failed!", where should i, if so, insert the .nextTag ?

Comment: I guess I was wrong then. I read the XmlPullParser docs and it seeems that you're doing everything fine. I'm not sure if I can help any further, sorry :(

Comment: Maybe I could help more if you posted a fragment of the xml (maybe a single ChannelPackage tag), the result your getting for that framgent, and the expected result.